# Target and output

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery. I have the html:

```
<fieldset id="question-10">
<p>
      <label>Question 10</label>
    </p>
    <p>Show .target's data attribute "sha1"'s value in .output.</p>
    <p class="target" data-sha1="92429d82a41e930486c6de5ebda9602d55c39986"></p>
    <p class="output"></p>
  </fieldset>
```

and my jQuery is

```
$("#question-10 .target").val(.output);
```

I am not sure what the code should read.

Comment: You set the text conent of an element through the `.text` method. Also your `.output` is missing quotes. Also, you access data attributes through the `.data` method. Generally - StackOverflow is a bad place to ask questions that aren't very specific - please tell us where specifically you're stuck.

Comment: what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is how u can get the data attribute from the `target` into the output

```
var item = $(".target").data("sha1");
$(".output").html(item);
```

Hope this helps

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/v9e9boxL/)

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` is used to read from & write to `input` field. You should use `.text()` instead.
To get the content of `output` class of `parent` id `question-10` use

```
$("#question-10 .target").text();
//or
$("#question-10 .target").html();
```

And to get specific `attribute` value: `$('selector').attr('attribute name')`
Example:

```
var test = $("#question-10 .target").attr('data-sha1');
alert(test); //output: 92429d82a41e930486c6de5ebda9602d55c39986
```

Also can use `.data()` for data `attribute`. ie,. `test = $("#question-10 .target").data('sha1');`

```
$("#question-10 .target").text("Desired content");
//or
$("#question-10 .target").html("Desired content");
```